# using WebView to view map and set marker (pin) on android

Tags: android, google-maps, webview, marker

I'm making an app on android, using webview to load google map (using this url for my webview: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-android-webmap/simple-android-map.html).
but i can't put a marker on that webview, can't somebody tell me how?

Comment: your URL there seems to be ideal if you wanna use webview in android since it's full screen map. based on the url this is just a sample. is there an official android web map URL we can use? i'm looking to do a map centric android app with a web view instead of map view so I can try to package the APK as a blackberry BAR.

Comment: i see now where your url came from https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3

Answer (score 3):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=37.423156,-122.084917
```

The above simply shows the directions screen with missing destination field.  If you want the pin to show on a simple map screen do this instead:

```
http://www.google.com/maps?q=37.423156,-122.084917
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly lots of ways to skin a cat - but I am loving the Google Static Maps API.

It generates a standard image (of desired size) and you can add points/lines/polygons all from a URL.

Whilst I haven't checked the terms, it is clearly possible to cache/store the result.

Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false

Answer (score -1):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=NJ
```

load URL like this pass address where you want to put the pin